# SailsJS - Create versioned API without blueprint

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, nginx, sails.js

I'm trying to figure out how to create a versionned API for my application.
According to this issue https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/322 , I have to use blueprint, but all blueprint is deactivated in my project (a wish from my boss).

I want to be able to have any URL like `http://myapi.com/v1/my-custom-route` , and so on for any version.

So far, the best way I've found is to duplicate all controller to something like `v322AuthController.js` and to map all routes like

```
'POST /v3.2.2/se-connecter'              : 'v322AuthController.perform_signin'
```

But I think that's an ugly trick. I'm currently using Nginx and all my code is versionned with git

Thank you if you have any idea

Kai23

Answer (score 1):

you have to disable all blueprints? Than you have to write all your routes an our own.

If you don't want to duplicate your controllers you can try this:

`config/routes.js`

```
module.exports.routes = {

 'post /:apiversion/se-connecter' : {
    controller: 'AuthController',
    action: 'perform_signin',
    skipAssets: true
 }
....
}
```

So Sails passes all */se-connecter to the method "perform_signin" at your "AuthController". In your controller you have your api-version:

`AuthController.js`

```
module.exports = {
   perform_signin: function (req, res) {

      var apiversion = req.param('apiversion');

      if (apiversion === "0.2.0") {
         ....
      }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach:

Create subfolder for your controllers as:

```
/controllers/v1/UserController.js
/controllers/v2/UserController.js
```

In your routes.js file, add as follow:

```
'POST /api/v2/user': 'v2/UserController.create',
'POST /api/v1/user': 'v2/UserController.create',
```

And in your policies.js, you can add middlewares like this:

```
  'v2/UserController': {
    'create': ['isAuthenticated','isAuthorized']
   }
```

My current sails' version is: 0.12.3